# Visual Studio 2010 C++ IDE shows #ifdef blocks greyed out

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, ide

We are using Visual Studio 2010 (C++) and as convenience for doing dual command-line and IDE builds we use batch files to invoke either the command-line build or the IDE.  In the batch file we do a "set CL=/D AAA /D BBB ...". Both the command-line and IDE builds obey the preprocessor flags defined in the CL line.  However, when the IDE is invoked via the batch file it shows the "#ifdef AAA" blocks greyed out and the wrong blocks enabled, which is not what we really want. We have a ton of solutions and many projects per solutions and it is not practical to set preprocessor directives on a per project basis. So we specify these in the batch file, which works fine for builds but makes for a bit of a mess in the IDE. Any ideas on getting the IDE to show the correct block of code enabled per the batch-file-specified preprocessor directives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Property Sheets](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsproject/archive/2009/06/23/inherited-properties-and-property-sheets.aspx) to set options that will be propagated thru the all of your projects.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Property Manager to create a property sheet containing your custom preprocessor directives. Then attach this property sheet to all of the projects in your solution.

The following blog article appears to have an excellent overview of the Property Manager, including screenshots. Focus on the section starting with the heading *How to Use Property Sheets*.

[Visual Studio 2010: Property Sheets and C++ Directories](http://blog.gockelhut.com/2009/11/visual-studio-2010-property-sheets-and.html)